# Как написать последовательный ввод многозначного числа на Verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga

Всем привет!
Нужно написать программу:

Число набирается на тумблерах по 4 разряда и последовательно выводится на
6 индикаторов. Набранный символ записывается после установки «1» на
входе разрешения записи.
1. Состояние S0 – начальное.
2. Состояние S1 – ожидание ввода. Время удержания 4 такта. Состояние
выхода U.
3. Далее, автомат переходит в состояние ввода S2. Состояние выхода In.
Время удержания состояния ввода – 2 такта.
4. Автомат переходит в состояние вывода S3 и выводит «_», если
разрешение не поступит, при поступившем разрешении ввода
выводится введенная цифра. Время удержания состояния вывода – 3
такта. Из состояния вывода автомат снова переходит в ожидание ввода.
Последовательный вывод можно организовать с помощью
демультиплексора.

Как написать такую программу на Verilog?
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Если вы продемонстрируете свои усилия по решению проблемы и предоставите некоторую информацию о платформе, которую вы используете, вероятность получения ответа на ваш вопрос увеличится.

Comment: Платформа FPGA (ПЛИС)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге сам написал.
Оставлю ссылку тут. Надеюсь, кому-нибудь поможет в написании подобных программ.

Исходный код: https://github.com/mamadaliev/sequent
Пример работы программы: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWEUiZvxiOs

P.S. Названия состояний были изменены

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, вы можете использовать оператор `case` внутри синхронного блока `always`, который срабатывает на каждом положительном или отрицательном фронте тактового сигнала `clk` (`clock`, ...) (`always@(posedge clk)`, `always@(negedge clk`)).

Будет четыре случая (по одному для каждого) и одно условие по умолчанию (`default`). В каждом состоянии вы можете иметь счетчик (`counter`), который увеличивается с каждым шагом `clk`. Состояние изменится (перейдет в следующее состояние), когда счетчик достигнет соответствующего значения. Если вы хотите, вы можете использовать только один счетный регистр, чтобы сделать работу.

Извините за мой плохой русский, надеюсь, ответ помог вам, или, по крайней мере, поможет другим, которые могут столкнуться с подобной проблемой в будущем.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!